# Как с помощью стримов можно оптимизировать код?

Tags: java, java-stream

Я со стримами практически не знаком, но мне мой преподаватель сказал, что оптимизируй код с помощью стримов, будет выглядеть качественней, чем такое количество кода как у тебя ))
С чего начать, куда смотреть, подскажите ))

```
@Override
    public Collection<JoinedDataRow<K, V1, V2>> join(Collection<DataRow<K, V1>> leftCollection, Collection<DataRow<K, V2>> rightCollection) {
        List<JoinedDataRow> joinedDataRows = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataRow objLft : leftCollection) {
            for (DataRow objRght : rightCollection) {
                if (objLft.getKey() == objRght.getKey() && objLft.getValue() != null && objRght.getValue() != null) {
                    JoinedDataRow elem = new JoinedDataRow(objLft.getKey(), objLft.getValue(), objRght.getValue());
                    joinedDataRows.add(elem);
                }
            }
        }
        return Collections.singleton(joinedDataRows.get(0));
    }
```

Comment: С использованием стримов код не будет более оптимизированным (даже наоборот, стримы создают дополнительный оверхед). Разве что можно улучшить читабельность.

Comment: Окей, а как на твой взгляд можно оптимизировать то, что уже есть ?

Comment: Под оптимизацией имеется ввиду выход из цикла по первому совпадению, т.к. `joinedDataRows.get(0)`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С использованием стримов код не будет более оптимизированным (даже наоборот, стримы создают дополнительный оверхед). Разве что можно улучшить читабельность.

В первом приближении на стримах это можно переписать так:

```
public Collection<JoinedDataRow<K, V1, V2>> join(Collection<DataRow<K, V1>> leftCollection, Collection<DataRow<K, V2>> rightCollection) {
    List<JoinedDataRow> joinedDataRows =
            leftCollection.stream()
                    .flatMap(
                            objLft -> rightCollection.stream()
                                    .filter(objRght -> objLft.getKey() == objRght.getKey())
                                    .filter(objRght -> objLft.getValue() != null)
                                    .filter(objRght -> objRght.getValue() != null)
                                    .map(objRght -> new JoinedDataRow(objLft.getKey(), objLft.getValue(), objRght.getValue()))
                    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return Collections.singleton(joinedDataRows.get(0));
}
```

---

Вместо `.collect()` можно сделать `.findFirst()`, если вас действительно интересует только первый элемент.

Comment: Ясно,спасибо тебе,буду пытаться разбираться со стримом,как говорится начало положено 

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно переписать следующим образом, отфильтровав сначала не-нулловые значения и воспользовавшись `findFirst` для поиска первого подходящего элемента.

Для сравнения обобщенных ключей следует использовать `equals/Objects.equals`, а не оператор равенства `==`, который будет проверять тождественность объектов.

Также следует предусмотреть обработку случая, когда не будет ни одного результата, возвращая хотя бы пустое множество (`Collections::emptySet`)

```java
@Override
public Collection<JoinedDataRow<K, V1, V2>> join(Collection<DataRow<K, V1>> leftCollection, Collection<DataRow<K, V2>> rightCollection) {
    return leftCollection
        .stream()
        .filter(left -> Objects.nonNull(left.getValue()))
        .flatMap(left -> rightCollection
                .stream()
                .filter(right -> left.getKey() == right.getKey() && Objects.nonNull(right.getValue()))
                .map(right -> new JoinedDataRow<>(left.getKey(), left.getValue(), right.getValue()))
        ) // Stream<JoinedDataRow>
        .findFirst()
        .map(Collections::singleton) // Optional<Set<JoinedDataRow>>
        .orElseGet(Collections::emptySet);
}
```